# SQL query using rows from another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use the results from one query to perform another query and combine the results into a single table.

The first query obtains a set of devices for a particular device version and date

```
SELECT        
    dbo.DeviceSession.SerialNumber, 
    dbo.DeviceSession.BackupDate
FROM
    dbo.DeviceSession
```

| SerialNumber | BackupDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-24 |
| 2 | 2022-02-08 |
| 3 | 2022-02-10 |

The second query obtains the number of errors for a particular serial number and backup date.

```
SELECT 
    ErrorCode, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM
    dbo.DeviceSession FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.DeviceSessionErrorLogEntry AS DeviceSessionErrorEntry_1 
        ON DeviceSession.Id = DeviceSessionErrorEntry_1.DeviceSessionId
WHERE   
    (dbo.DeviceSession.DeviceSerial LIKE '1') AND  
    (dbo.DeviceSession.BackupDate LIKE '2022-01-24')
GROUP BY ErrorCode
```

| ErrorCode | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 97 | 2 |
| 150 | 5 |

The second query can be combined into a single line by using the "FOR XML PATH('')"

```
SELECT 
    ErrorCode, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM 
    dbo.DeviceSession 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.DeviceSessionErrorLogEntry AS DeviceSessionErrorEntry_1 
        ON DeviceSession.Id = DeviceSessionErrorEntry_1.DeviceSessionId
WHERE   
    (dbo.DeviceSession.DeviceSerial LIKE '1') 
    AND (dbo.DeviceSession.BackupDate LIKE '2022-01-24')
GROUP BY ErrorCode
FOR XML PATH('')
```

| XML_FDEWFJEWFOE |
| --- |
| <ErrorCode>97</ErrorCode><Count>2</Count><ErrorCode>150</ErrorCode><Count>5</Count> |

How would I create a query such that I could obtain a table that lists the total errors for every serial number and backup date from the first query?

Desired output:

| SerialNumber | BackupDate | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-24 | <ErrorCode>97</ErrorCode><Count>2</Count><ErrorCode>150</ErrorCode><Count>5</Count> |
| 2 | 2022-02-08 | <ErrorCode>97</ErrorCode><Count>5</Count> |
| 3 | 2022-02-10 | <ErrorCode>42</ErrorCode><Count>1</Count> |

Comment: The second query cannot run in SQL Server. It's probably missing a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: The DeviceSession conditions in the WHERE clause makes your FULL OUTER JOIN return LEFT JOIN result. Move those to the ON clause to get true FULL OUTER JOIN result.

Comment: Why `LIKE` instead of `=`? Also you should alias the tables instead of using 3-part column naming

Comment: LIKE instead of = since I had some wildcard matching previously. I eliminated that to simplify the example.

Thanks, I added the GROUP BY. I left this out while trying to simplify my example also.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your error log query into a correlated subquery that references DeviceSession in the outer query. Something like the following:

```
DECLARE @DeviceSession TABLE (ID INT, SerialNumber INT, BackupDate DATE)
INSERT @DeviceSession
VALUES
    (101, 1, '2022-01-24'),
    (102, 2, '2022-02-08'),
    (103, 3, '2022-02-10')

DECLARE @DeviceSessionErrorLogEntry TABLE (ID INT, DeviceSessionID INT, ErrorCode INT)
INSERT @DeviceSessionErrorLogEntry
VALUES
    (201, 101, 97),
    (202, 101, 150),
    (203, 101, 150),
    (204, 101, 97),
    (205, 101, 150),
    (206, 102, 97),
    (207, 102, 150),
    (208, 102, 150)

SELECT
    DS.SerialNumber,
    DS.BackupDate,
    Notes = (
        SELECT EL.ErrorCode, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
        FROM @DeviceSessionErrorLogEntry EL
        WHERE DS.Id = EL.DeviceSessionId
        GROUP BY EL.ErrorCode
        ORDER BY EL.ErrorCode
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    )
FROM @DeviceSession DS
ORDER BY DS.SerialNumber
```

Results:

| SerialNumber | BackupDate | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-24 | `<ErrorCode>97</ErrorCode><Count>2</Count><ErrorCode>150</ErrorCode><Count>3</Count>` |
| 2 | 2022-02-08 | `<ErrorCode>97</ErrorCode><Count>1</Count><ErrorCode>150</ErrorCode><Count>2</Count>` |
| 3 | 2022-02-10 | NULL |

The subquery can also be moved to a `CROSS APPLY` if you would like to separate subquery details from the final select for readability.

If you really need a full outer join (to show error records that have no matching session), the query would need some restructuring with an `FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DeviceSessionId FROM @DeviceSessionErrorLogEntry EL) IDS ON IDS.DeviceSessionId = DS.Id`, and then have the Notes subquery reference those IDs.

Comment: Thank you so much!